# Rails 3 inherited_resources ignores 'defaults' setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, inherited-resources

I'm using Inherited resources for my controllers. And now i have model:

```
class Sms < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And i want controller for it, where i make defaults:

```
class Admin::SmsesController < Admin::InheritedResources
  defaults :resource_class => Sms,
           :collection_name => 'smses',
           :instance_name => 'sms'
end
```

but i can not understand, why it still trying to get "Smse" model:

```
NameError in Admin::SmsesController#index
uninitialized constant Smse
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Rails doesn't know that the plural of Sms is Smses. If you go to the Rails console you should see that:

```
> "Sms".pluralize
 => "Sms"

> "Smses".singularize
 => "Smse"
```

When faced with a plural it doesn't recognise, singularize just truncates the final "s", which is why your app is looking for a nonexistent Smse model.

You will save yourself a lot of headaches by configuring Rails to pluralize/singularize your models correctly. In the file config\initializers\inflections.rb you should find some examples of how to do this. What you want is:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'sms', 'smses'
end
```

Then I don't think you should need to put the defaults option in there at all - it should all work out of the box.